# Java Lock and condition in RailwayStation.java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, conditional-statements

This is the example which I picked from OCPJ SE7.
some how program just stuck in WaitForJoe class and only output I got is as below. though sometime I got the complete otput.

> IC1122 - Madrid to Paris  Locking in train class
>
> IC1122 - Madrid to Paris: I've arrived in station
>
> IC1122 - Madrid to Paris  sending signal
>
> Waiting in the station for IC1122 in which Joe is coming
>
> Thread-1  Locking in WaitForJoe class

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class MyStack {

    private static Lock station = new ReentrantLock();

    private static Condition joeArrival = station.newCondition();
    //private static Condition syncc = station.newCondition();
    public static volatile boolean flag = false ;

    static class Train extends Thread {
        public Train(String name) {
            this.setName(name);
        }
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(getName() +"  Locking in train class");

            station.lock();
            try {
                System.out.println(getName() + ": I've arrived in station ");
                if(getName().startsWith("IC1122")) {
                    System.out.println(getName() +"  sending signal ");
                    while (!flag){}
                    joeArrival.signalAll();
                }
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println(getName() +"  UnLocking in train class");
                station.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    static class WaitForJoe extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Waiting in the station for IC1122 in which Joe is coming");
            System.out.println(getName() +"  Locking in WaitForJoe class");
            
            station.lock();
            System.out.println( "    unlocking " + station.toString());
            try {
                System.out.println(getName() +"  waiting !!!!");
                flag = true ;
                joeArrival.await();
                System.out.println("Pick up Joe and go home");
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println(getName() +"  UnLocking in WaitForJoe class");
                station.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Train("IC1122 - Madrid to Paris").start();
    
        new WaitForJoe().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question exacly ?

Comment: System.out.println("Pick up Joe and go home");
 is not in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that nothing is waiting on joeArrival when the signal is sent. Signalling a Condition only wakes up threads which are currently waiting on it. And in your program, WaitForJoe and Train are mutually excluded from running together by the station lock. So, when Train has the lock on station WaitForJoe is waiting for it. Train doesn't unlock station until after it's sent the signal to joeArrival and so WaitForJoe doesn't wait on joeArrival until after the signal has been sent.

You can get the complete output when the WaitForJoe thread gets the station lock first. In that case, the ReentrantLock is released when it awaits on the Condition and the Train thread does actually end up signalling it.

Have you considered using a CountDownLatch to model this interaction? It greatly simplifies the implementation...

```
private static CountDownLatch joeArrival = new CountDownLatch(1);
public static volatile boolean flag = false ;

static class Train extends Thread {
    public Train(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() +"  Locking in train class");

        System.out.println(getName() + ": I've arrived in station ");
        if(getName().startsWith("IC1122")) {
            System.out.println(getName() +"  sending signal ");
            while (!flag){}
            joeArrival.countDown();
        }

    }
}

static class WaitForJoe extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Waiting in the station for IC1122 in which Joe is coming");
        System.out.println(getName() +"  Locking in WaitForJoe class");

        try {
            System.out.println(getName() +"  waiting !!!!");
            flag = true ;
            joeArrival.await();
            System.out.println("Pick up Joe and go home");
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```